# Missing Add To button in photos app on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, photos.app, album

On my iPhone 7, I go and open up photos, then click on "select" photos. I then select a photo. There used to be a "Add to" button in the middle of the bottom (to the left is "upload" and to the right the "trash" button).

The "add to" (which allowed me to send the photo to another folder) is no longer there. Disappeared.

Hope that explains it better.

How do I add this photos to other albums?

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem- what is the answer??

Comment: That's weird, I see that button. What is your OS version?

Comment: My current version is 13.1.2 but I just updated that. The missing button was already gone in the previous version.